# How to get MONGO docs based on few combinations having more that once

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to get mongo docs based on few combinations having more that once
in the below docs i need combination of `"Location"`,`"Company"`,`"start"`,`"end"` for only "Id" : "Q1D3" having this combination more than once but `INT_ID` will be different

```
{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1234",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1235",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1236",
    "Location" : "USA",
    "Company" : "COMP3",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1237",
    "Location" : "USA",
    "Company" : "COMP3",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D5",
    "INT_ID" : "1237",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D5",
    "INT_ID" : "1239",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}


{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1237",
    "Location" : "CAN",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}
```

from the above example i need to query only to get docs

```
{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1234",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1235",
    "Location" : "ENG",
    "Company" : "COMP1",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1236",
    "Location" : "USA",
    "Company" : "COMP3",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}

{
    "Id" : "Q1D3",
    "INT_ID" : "1237",
    "Location" : "USA",
    "Company" : "COMP3",
    "start" : 20191001,
    "end" : 20230930
}
```

can some one please help me on this

Comment: You can try to implement yourself by referring this implementation [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-all-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-by-a-key-field)

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

- `$match` your condition
- `$group` by `Location`, `Company`, `start` and `end` fields and make array of documents in `doc`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `doc` array
- $group by `INT_ID` and first `doc`
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `doc` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { Id: "Q1D3" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Location: "$Location",
        Company: "$Company",
        start: "$start",
        end: "$end"
      },
      doc: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$doc" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$doc.INT_ID",
      doc: { $first: "$doc" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IYuq94ACKQj)